# parsing a text file from HTML file

Tags: html, html-parsing

I have a text file Information.txt which has following data:

```
United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees,www.unhcr.org
United Nations Children's Fund,www.unicef.org
United Nations Conference on Trade and Development,www.unctad.org
United Nations Development Programme,www.undp.org
```

And I have a HTML document that pretty much does nothing.

```
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Reading from text files</title>
    </head>
    <body>
</html>
```

I need to read Information.txt from this HTML document, and print each line. I am completely NEW to this thing. I have read many articles but they all talk about using javascript or python library. Is there a way I can read this file and put the data in body of the HTML document.
Any headsup will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it right, that you have the text file on the server? Or do you want to read it from your local file system? Where do you store the HTML file? On your file system or on a server?

Comment: Text file is on local system. HTML file is also stored on local system

Answer (score 0):

HTML cannot do that, all it does is display text. If you make it a .php file, the following will work:

```
<head>
<title>Reading from text files</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$f = fopen("Information.txt", "r");

// Read line by line until end of file
while(!feof($f)) { 
    echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
}

fclose($f);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Full tutorial and credit here: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson15.php
As you use Information.txt and they use unitednations.txt with the same data, I figure you might've already found it there.

Just as a tip: don't be reluctant to use a new language. HTML is just a simple displayer and is a basis to start from.

Comment: Did you make it a .php file and are you running it in an environment which is capable of using php?
If not, then you'd better hardcode it into HTML.

Comment: I did make it as .php file, I ran it on chrome. What do you mean by capable environment?

Comment: These are the very basics of running and using php. HTML can be read directly from your browser, javascript can be directly executed by your browser, but PHP is a server side language. It's meant to be executed by a server before being sent to your browser.
Look for a server that supports PHP here: http://www.free-webhosts.com/free-php-webhosting.php
Make an account and upload your files with ftp (both the php and the txt file) and you'll be able to run them. Look up tutorials and read them to get the whole picture, it's the basics of getting into building websites.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Information.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#p_element").text(data);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p id="p_element"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

You have to store the above HTML file in the same folder as `Information.txt`. In the above code example I use JavaScript with the library [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/). The file was loaded via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

Some notes: JavaScript runs normally on the browser and therefore on the client's machine. It is really powerful but has the disadvantage that not every client support it (such as Google bots so that JavaScript only websites without any logic on Server side cannot be indexed by Google). You can also generate the HTML on the server side via PHP or python libraries. The above example uses the JavaScript Version. @Frezzo posted a solution with PHP.

If you are new to this topic: You can use the above example as a starting point. Here are links to the used functions of jQuery:

- [$.ajax(...)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [$(function () { ... })](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)
- [.text(...)](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [$("#p_element")](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

Look for good tutorials in JavaScript, too.